# Upgrading to Sonarqube TFS Extension From 3.0.0 to 4.0.1

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, upgrade

On TFS 2015, I upgraded from 3.0.0 to 4.0.1, however the new 4.0 tasks are not showing up in the tasks list.

When I try to reinstall 4.0, I get confirmation that it is already installed:

[Shows version is already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ubAT.png)

[However the new 4.0 related tasks are now showing up in the tasks list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiVnY.png)

[I do still see the version 3.0 tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a28rD.png)

Is 4.0.1 compatible with TFS 2015? How do I get the 4.0 tasks to show up in the tasks list?

In TFS 2018, a new installation of 4.0 works just fine:

[4.0 Tasks Showing Up in TFS2018 after initial installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64DYB.png)

Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Comment: 2nd image description should read: However the new 4.0 related tasks are **NOT** showing up in the tasks list

Comment: Do you use TFS 2015 Update 3?

Comment: I'm on TFS 2015 Update 4

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall the extension.

Comment: Tried in our dev instance, uninstalling also removed 3.0 step already setup on existing build definitions. 4.0 installation looks to be successful, however the new tasks still did not show up on the build tasks list.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the following bug: [VSTS-135](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VSTS-135)

TL;DR: version 4 of the extension uses a mechanism that is available only starting with TFS 2017 Update 2.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The link provides a lot of information but unsure what to do to get 4.0 working in TFS2015 Update 4. Do you mind elaborating on steps needed to fix the issue?

Comment: You won't be able to upgrade to version 4.0 on TFS 2015. This new version was rewritten in Node.js to be portable on different OS (Linux or macOS agents), which makes it not compatible with TFS 2015.